# Regex in JavaScript is not matching a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this JavaScript code:

```
var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
var content = textareas[0].value;
var reg = new RegExp(/^.*[[]#.+#[]].*$/mgi);
var res = content.match(reg); // always null
```

The content var contains a long multiline string that contains patterns like `[#some text goes here#]`. I tested the regex with some online testing tools and it works against the string. Using the regex in JavaScript fails though - any idea why?

Thanks!

Comment: You're using `^` and `$` along with the `m` modifier. So does this mean that you only want to match when the `[#some text goes here#]` is the only thing on the line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
var content = 'foo\nhead [#some text goes here#] tail\nbar';
var reg = new RegExp(/\[#.+#\]/mgi);
var res = content.match(reg);
```

On execution, `res` contains the string `'[#some text goes here#]'`.

Note that I have escaped `[` and `]`. If they are not escaped, anything enclosed within them forms a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Comment: @EOB: If it doesn't work for you, then you havent' properly described the result you want.

Comment: Aha, now it works! Dont know what the problem was ... I had the same just with [[] instead of \\[ ... propably some tiny mistake somewhere, anyway, it works now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You used `[[]` to escape `[`, which is fine, but you can't use `[]]` to escape `]` because it the first `]` ends the character class in the regex. This works fine:

```
/^.*\[#.+#\].*$/mgi
```

In the case that you only want the single block and not the entire line, use:

```
/\[#.+#\]/mgi
```

Comment: [[] is the same as \\[, isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

This should capture the text between hashes (e.g., "some text here"):

```
var reg = /[^\[]*\[#([^\#]+)#\]/gims
```